# How to install windows from a .iso file

Tags: windows

My system is running on windows 10 on 500GB SATA. I've windows xp installation files (setup.exe etc) that i m trying to install on another 128GB SSD drive. I don't have a USB. Can someone please guide what are possible options?

Comment: Write your ISO to CD/DVD-R/RW and install XP from it. If you do not want to damage your Win10 bootfiles, detach your HDD before installation.

Comment: I tried `Win2USB` utility to read from .iso file and copy but it gave this error while reading .iso file: `cannot find bootable image (0x0000000C,,,)`. Do you know what this means?

Comment: If so your ISO is not install disk ISO, it is filecopy. Bootblock is lost. Add it into ISO, then burn.

Comment: Where to find bootblock for winXP?

Comment: Find any Windows XP installation ISO copy. Download it. Open in any ISO editor. Remove all files, but do not remove bootblock. Copy files from your ISO to it. Burn.

Comment: I downloaded another .iso win xp. do you know where bootblock file is normally stored and/or what is its name?

Comment: Bootblock is stored out of file space. Edit this downloaded ISO by any ISO editor/burner which can work with bootblocks (extract, add/replace, check ISO is bootable). After edition, before saving edited ISO, check that ISO is bootable (sometimes it can be errorneously removed when all files from file space of ISO are removed - so be safe during edition - or extract bootblock before edition to file and insert it back after files replace before save/burn).

Comment: This new .iso for win xp i just downloaded is giving me the same error message (`cannot find bootable image (0x00000C...)` while reading it using `Win2USB` ???

Comment: Maybe it is Win2USB problem? simply try to burn your ISO and then to boot from burned disk...

Comment: Try to use [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/en_IE.html) to create the boot.

Answer (score -1):

What I finally did was to download .iso image file for windows 10 using torrent. Luckily I found the best WIN10 (activated and updateable). I bought a blank DVD (8.5gb) from a local store and using Imgburn utility, I burned .iso file to DVD and finally installed Windows 10.

Hope it helps.